# Binding a Class public variable to an element in xaml for validation

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, xaml, mvvm

I know this question might have been asked many a times but i am unable to find an answer. i am a beginner with wpf programming. I am trying to implement different validations in wpf. My code is

**MyValidation.cs**

```
namespace InterviewQues
{
   public class MyValidation:INotifyPropertyChanged
   {
        private string name;

    public string NameProperty
    {   get 
        {

            return name;
        }
        set {

            name = value;

            OnPropertyChanged(name);

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
            {
                throw new ApplicationException("Name is Mandatory...");
            }


        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propName)
    {

        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
        }

    }

}
}
```

**MainWindowXAML.cs**

```
<Window x:Class="InterviewQues.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:c="clr-namespace:InterviewQues"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">


<Window.Resources>
    <c:MyValidation x:Key="MyValidation"></c:MyValidation>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Label Content="Name : " Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="99,22,0,0" Name="label4" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="57" />
    <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,23,170,0" Name="textBox4" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" >
        <TextBox.Text>
            <Binding Path="NameProperty">
                <Binding.ValidationRules>
                    <ExceptionValidationRule></ExceptionValidationRule>
                </Binding.ValidationRules>
            </Binding>
        </TextBox.Text>
    </TextBox>
</Grid>
```

this validation is not working and i am unable to understand.

Whatever i have studied so far i understood this way even after implementing inotify... it is still not working.

i know data context can work here but i want validation layer to be seperate as it will be used by viewmodel in MVVM pattern.

please help.....

Comment: `OnPropertyChanged(name);` should be `OnPropertyChanged("NameProperty");`

Comment: no its not working with NameProperty as well

Comment: I didn't say it was the only problem.

Answer (score 0):

Consider implmenting INotifyDateErrorInfo on your view model. It does similar to INotifyPropertyChanged but is targeted specifically at notifying your view of properties with invalid values.

The followng might be useful : [Easy MVVM Example With INotifyPropertyChanged And INotifyDataErrorInfo](http://blog.micic.ch/net/easy-mvvm-example-with-inotifypropertychanged-and-inotifydataerrorinfo)

Hope that helps.

A typical implementation I use for ViewModel properties, which I wrap in a snippet is:

```
public string CurrentTime
    {
        get
        {
            if (this._CurrentTime == null)
            {
                this._CurrentTime = default(string);
            }

            return this._CurrentTime;
        }

        set
        {
            if (value != null && !value.Equals(this._CurrentTime))
            {
                this._CurrentTime = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("CurrentTime");
            }
        }
    }
```

This supports lazy get and tests the value in the setter before making the update. If you're intending to stop the value being set then just add to the if condition in the setter. However, this will cause binding sync issues with the UI potentially showing the value but the property not, or it may update the UI back to the previous value which is bad user experience. Look at using the error handling as referenced in the link above, that way you keep the value the user has given but they get visual feedback, in the form of red borders that values are not correct.

Comment: is there any error in the code i have written , if this a simple class inclusion without using datacontext.

Comment: As mentioned by Henk Holterman, you've got an error calling OnPropertyChanged where the property name should be provided.

This is another interface for you to implement but it ties in with WPF bindings very well and lets you validate your data in your viewmodel - which I think is what you were after?

Comment: Updated my answer with an example of INotifyPropertyChanged